# How to reverse arrow direction of the tree (from leaves to root) in JUNG?

Tags: java, graph, tree, jung

I am new to JUNG. I have drawn my tree, however need to reverse arrow's direction from child to parent vertices.

```
    TreeLayout<VertexLiteral, EdgeLiteral> treeLayout=
            new TreeLayout<VertexLiteral, EdgeLiteral>(tree);
    VisualizationViewer<VertexLiteral, EdgeLiteral> vv =
            new VisualizationViewer<VertexLiteral,EdgeLiteral>(treeLayout, new Dimension(600,600));
```

Any solution?

Cheers

Comment: Do you want to just render the edges differently (i.e., put the arrowheads on the other end of the edge), or do you want a different data model (you want nodes to have multiple 'parents')?

Comment: I only need to render edges differently as you said put the arrowheads on the other end of the edge. Thanks Joshua.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can provide your own edge renderer, or customize BasicEdgeRenderer so that it draws the arrows at the other end.  Should be pretty easy, I.e. a one or two line change inside drawSimpleEdge.

Answer (score 0):

Following the idea proposed by **Joshua O'Madadhain**, as a quick-and-dirty fix:

1) copy BasicEdgeRenderer source code into a BasicEdgeRenderer_ReverseArrow class

2) In that class, swap v1 and v2 in

```
V v1 = endpoints.getFirst();
V v2 = endpoints.getSecond();
```

3) Add this modified renderer to your code as follows:

```
vv.getRenderer().setEdgeRenderer(new BasicEdgeRenderer_ReverseArrow<State, String>());
```

Nicolas